# Editing form data in django

Tags: django, forms, crud

I am trying to edit a form data but instead of editing, it adds new data. I actually referred the codes online, but I couldn't figure out where I have got wrong.
The following is the snippet of where I call the edit button

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'ride:edit-ride' i.id %}">Edit</a></td>
```

veiws.py

```
def edit_ride(request, pk):
    obj = Ride.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = RideForm(instance=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RideForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('ride_list.html')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'offerride/create_ride.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code look fine , I think you might have forgot to change the view name connected to edit_ride url. create_ride view might be still there connected with edit_ride url.I hope !!!

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate a bit on it

Comment: i think you should check the urls.py and make sure you connected 'edit_ride' view with 'edit_view path'  path(' editview / <int:pk> ',views.edit_view)

Comment: There is no mistake in that. Any way thanks for the suggestion. Could you help me check if there is anything wrong other than this?